# Azure Portal missing Web App

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service

I have a number of web apps hosted in Azure. These can be navigated to by their URL and are live and running correctly. If I use the server browser in Visual Studio 2015 I can see the correct web apps... AND previously deleted web apps.

However in the new Azure portal one of my web apps is missing. What do I need to do to get the new portal to recognise all of my web apps and should I be worried about visual studio displaying old deleted ones?

Comment: If your talking about on the that initial dashboard thats normal.  Click on that hamburger on the far left side and click "All Resources" is your stuff in there?

Comment: I've searched in the "All Resources". It's not in there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sync issue that happens occasionally, and that we can fix for you. In order to do this, please share the name of any site in your subscription. You can create a temporary dummy site for that purpose if you like.

Comment: One of the sites is called "thebeautifulnorth". This one appears correctly at the moment. Is this a known issue with a fix planned?

Comment: Ok, it should be fixed now. Yes, I believe there are upcoming changes that should avoid this in the first place.